# using sed to remove lines in a file

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
Heading - 
  - Completed foo
    - More information
    - Still more
  * Need to complete bar
  - Did baz (comment blah blah) ***

Another - 
  * Need to complete foo
  - Completed bar (blah comment blah) ***
  - Done baz
```

I need to run the text file through `sed` to remove all of the lines that start with spaces (number varies) and a hyphen, and another space.

What is the regex or pattern I need to use with `sed` to make the output look like this below?

```
Heading - 
  * Need to complete bar

Another - 
  * Need to complete foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [Phoshi](https://superuser.com/users/6998/phoshi)'s answer, assisted by [Dennis Williamson](https://superuser.com/users/310/dennis-williamson), to help me come up with `sed /^\s+-\s.*/d` which works as expected.

Comment: You could use `+` instead of `*` to make sure there's at least one space.

Answer (score 2):

`"s/\s*-\s.*//g"` should do it, I think.

That's \s to match a space, * to match zero or more of the preceding character (the space), a literal hyphen character, then another space, then .+ to match everything after it.

Comment: Close. Very close!  This leaves blank lines.  It does not remove the carriage return/line feed.

Comment: damn! Try appending a \s to the search string, then, I'm afraid I don't do enough work on full lines :P

Answer (score 1):

You should use egrep or grep for this task, sed is a stream editor, grep is more in line with the line-at-a-time philosophy.

You need a regex that matches the start of line, whitespace, hyphen, space. Sounds like this would work:

```
egrep  -v  '^[ ]+-[ ]' filename
```

The `-v` option causes egrep to REMOVE the matching lines -- this is easier than building a regex that rejects the lines.

Example:

```
 nobody$ egrep -v  '^[ ]+-[ ]' /tmp/foof
 Heading - 
   * Need to complete bar

 Another - 
   * Need to complete foo
 nobody$ cat /tmp/foof
 Heading - 
   - Completed foo
     - More information
     - Still more
   * Need to complete bar
   - Did baz (comment blah blah) ***

 Another - 
   * Need to complete foo
   - Completed bar (blah comment blah) ***
   - Done baz
 nobody$ _
```

Dealing with Tab characters only means you need them  in the bracket expressions,but that's hard to show online.

Comment: With tabs: `egrep -v $'^[ \t]+-[ \t]' /tmp/foof`

Answer (score 0):

For filtering entire lines from the output, you usually want `grep`, not `sed`. In particular, to exclude specific lines, you'll want to use `grep -v 'exclusion-regex'`.

Comment: i dont see _why_ one _wants_ 'grep' instead of 'sed' .. except for more complex syntax. so, why is using grep for filtering stuff out better than the 'd' command of 'sed'?